# Misplaced UISegmentedControl (potential bug)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uitabbar, nslayoutconstraint

I'm pretty new to using Apple `NSAutolayout`. In the easiest example I could imagine I created tabbed iPhone App with default template. Then in first view i added `UISegmentedControl` and add 2 constraints to him: "Align Center X to: SuperView" and "Bottom Space to: Bottom Layout Guide". Then when I run app the `UISegmentedControl` position is correct but when I switch to the second view and go back, the `UISegmentedControl` goes down and becomes hidden by `UITabBar`. When I rotate device the segmented control position goes back to the right place.

Is there a solution to avoid this?

EDIT: Few snapshots to show problem.

[Before http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/6830/o2v2.png](http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/6830/o2v2.png)
[After http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2205/ksb6.png](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2205/ksb6.png)

EDIT 2: I found temporary solution.

All you need to store data using property for example:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect fix_didLoadSegmentedFrame;
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` and function where you handle value changing `UISegmentedControl` you should add line:

```
self.fix_didLoadSegmentedFrame = self.mapTypeSegmentedControl.frame;
```

You should also set "Apply retina 3.5-inch from factor" storyboard property.

Comment: I have same issue. +1 for nice problem explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey. There two possibilities to remove such issue:

- check option "remove at build time"
- attach `UISegmentedControl` to superview NOT to the top layer

Answer (score 1):

Try using this in viewDidLoad:

self.tabBarController.tabBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: It doesn't solve problem. Transparent view is still present uncorrectly. But it solves ugly "jumping" so +1

Comment: Anyway I was suprised when i set bottom bar to "Opaque Bottom Bar" in Storyboard it still doesn't work correctly.